# point iframe to webserivce to downlaod file

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, download

Is it possible to specify a web service as the source for an iFrame?

I am trying to get File Download working but since my file is stored as Binary in SQL Server, i cannot point user to the specific file. I have to fetch the file, process it and prompt user to save/open dialog. I was wondering if there is a way i can point an iFrame to a webservice call which will be responsible for processing the file download request?

I have tried the below code but it doesnt work.

Any idea what am i missing here?

```
<iframe id="downloadFrame" style="display:none"></iframe>

<input  type="button" value="Download File" title="Download File" onclick = "JavaScript: return downloadFlie();" />

    function downloadFlie()
    {
        var iframe = document.getElementById("downloadFrame");
        iframe.src = "Services/svcAttachments.asmx/DownloadFile?FileId=5";
        return false
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just use an anchor and a target?

```
<a href="Services/svcAttachments.asmx/DownloadFile?FileId=5" target="_blank">Download</a>
```

Comment: Thank you. this works but opens a new window. I was trying to use iFrame to make it feel like everything happened on the same page.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a generic handler (*.ashx) for this purpose.

I've googled this sample for you: http://geekswithblogs.net/hmloo/archive/2012/03/07/how-to-download-files-using-a-generic-handler.aspx

Comment: Thank you. this works but opens a new window. I was trying to use iFrame to make it feel like everything happened on the same page.

Comment: @Asdfg: Opening a link in a new tab is ihmo consired as standard. Also you should consider, that most users wouldn't event recognize the behaviour that you plannend.